# How do I check the uptime of a GCE instance using Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-stackdriver

What options do I have to check the uptime of a GCE instance ?

1. Do I need to install a monitoring agent , in the documentation for monitoring though it only mentions about uptime check of an Apache server insatalled on the GCE instance , how can I check if the GCE instance itself is up or not if it does not have a webserver on it  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few options.

If you are running some service on the instance, you probably want [Stackdriver Uptime Checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/uptime-checks), which will verify that your service is available and serving traffic. If you simply want to know if the instance is up (i.e., not stopped), you can use the [`compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-compute) metric. Neither of those two options needs the monitoring agent installed.

If you are trying to check that the instance is actually up and running processes, then you'll likely want the monitoring agent. Even in that case, there are a few possibilities. The agent monitors its own uptime via the [`agent.googleapis.com/agent/uptime`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent-agent) metric, or you could monitor for the presence of a specific process via the [processes metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent-processes).

Comment: How do I create an uptime check to check if an instance is up though?when I create an uptime check it asks for check type http, tcp etc , do I need to provide that protocol  info? Can stackdriver just check if the instance is up without me having to provide the details about the type of the check ?

Comment: Uptime checks are for checking whether your HTTP/TCP service is available and serving traffic. If all you want to know is whether the instance itself is up, please see the other options I've outlined in my answer.

Comment: @IgorPeshansky Which Aggregator suits for checking the availability of VM instances with this metric compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime . The requirement is to get an alert when the VM is down , tried few aggregators but couldn't get the expected results.

Comment: @DeenaDhayal If you want to alert when the instance is down (i.e., the uptime metric is no longer generated), you should use metric absence alerts (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/types-of-conditions#metric-absence).